# CSS Show Submenu on hover of a href

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I' am actually badly stuck and can't figure this out. Whenever someone hovers the on 1st level of the link. The 2nd Submenu / Children of current hovered menu should show up. Below are more information. I have been through this type of issues but kind of no brainer at the moment after 40 Minutes of research and trying am here.

**HTML :**

```
<ul id="header_topbar_ul">
    <?php
    global $db;
    $db->SELECT("SELECT * FROM modules WHERE modules_status='1' AND modules_show_in_menu='1' AND modules_parent_id='0' ORDER BY modules_order ASC");
    if($db->num_rows()){
        foreach($db->rows() as $menu){
            $modules_id = $menu["modules_id"];
            $modules_name = $menu["modules_name"];
            $modules_slug = $menu["modules_slug"];
    ?>
    <li id="header_<?php echo $modules_id; ?>">
        <a href="<?php echo $modules_slug; ?>" title="Dashboard"><?php echo $modules_name; ?></a>

        <?php
            $db->SELECT("SELECT * FROM modules WHERE modules_parent_id='$modules_id' AND modules_status='1' ORDER BY modules_order ASC");
            if($db->num_rows()){                    
        ?>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <?php
                    foreach($db->rows() as $submenu){
                        $modules_id = $menu["modules_id"];
                        $modules_name = $menu["modules_name"];
                        $modules_slug = $menu["modules_slug"];
                ?>
                    <li id="header_<?php echo $modules_id; ?>"><a href="<?php echo $modules_slug; ?>" title="Dashboard"><?php echo $modules_name; ?></a></li>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
            </ul>
        <?php
            }
        ?>

    </li>

    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</ul>
```

---

**CSS :**

```
#header_navigation #header_topbar_ul ul.submenu{
    display: none;  
}

#header_navigation #header_topbar_ul li a:hover ul.submenu{
    display: block !important;
    background: #000;
}
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is here

```
#header_navigation #header_topbar_ul li a:hover ul.submenu
                                               ^
```

You will need `+` there

```
#header_navigation #header_topbar_ul li a:hover + ul.submenu
```

As `ul.submenu` is not nested under `a` but it's adjacent to `a` element so use adjacent selector to select the `ul.submenu` on hover of `a`.

---

It will be even more better if you use direct descendant selector, to make your selector more specific, like

```
#header_navigation #header_topbar_ul > li > a:hover + ul.submenu
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
#header_navigation #header_topbar_ul li:hover ul.submenu{
    display: block !important;
    background: #000;
}
```

as ul is children of li and when you hover on li then the ul.submenu will appear or use as @Mr.Alien said.